# Using NgModel to bind to radio group input for Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a radio group that I want to set the value of from my component code. However I cannot seem to set the initial value using `[(ngModel)]`. I don't get any errors or anything to show why it is not showing the radio button selected.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <mat-radio-group  [(ngModel)]="selectedStatus" formControlName="completed">
    <mat-radio-button  [value]="1">Call Complete</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button [value]="2">Call Incomplete</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```

Component code snippets:

```
selectedStatus: Array<string>;

private initForm() {
    this.eventEditForm = new FormGroup({          
      'completed': new FormControl()
      });          
      this.selectedStatus = this.data[0].completed;
    }
```

`this.data[0].completed` returns 1 or 2 from a data service.

Comment: Well, selectedStatus is supposed to be 1, or 2. But you declared it as an Array<string>. It should be a number, because 1, and 2, are numbers. The compiler error message should tell you that. Why don't you read it?

Comment: The compiler is not showing any errors. I had tried it with number and it had no effect. So a little confused.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable **`selectedStatus`**  should not be a array of strings, it should be a number, change it as.

```
selectedStatus:  number ;
```

**[`WORKING STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-frmsud?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: stackblitz link is dead :-(

Comment: In Angular Material 7, `formControlName` becomes -> `name` (`@Input()
name: string`).
https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api
"Name of the radio button group. All radio buttons inside this group will use this name."